# How can I report all errors from a wrapper program or %include programs and report at the end of the program?

Tags: sql, error-handling, sas, workflow

I’m building a large workflow of programs using a wrapper program and %include statements. At the end of the program I have included a macro to send an email to the user alerting them that the program has completed. I’d like to include any errors that happened in the workflow and in which %include program they happened in. Does anyone have any experience trying something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this related to the SQL language?

Comment: I'm open to proc sql solutions for this issue

Comment: Did you include the `SOURCE` option for your `%INCLUDE` to have the errors and warnings printed to the log. I'm not sure what you're looking for exactly but it may be a 'log parser' but EG/Studio provide easy ways to navigate this already.

Comment: Use this google search to find solutions out there: `log parser site:lexjansen.com`